# Laravel Email Verification 5.8 with sqlsrv

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-5.8

I implemented the email verification that Laravel offers out of the box but currently have an issue when one click on the verification link sent on email. It brings the error: *Data Missing*

This error is throw by `Carbon` at the point when the column `email_verified_at` is being updated, and this was only on the SQLSRV implementation. I switched to a test MySQL database and this worked, although I need it to work with SQLSRV. I have not checked to see if any other database implementation encounters this problem.

Comment: Please show your code of the implementation you got so far.

Comment: @Namoshek I did not alter the laravel out of the box code.

Comment: Okay, then please share the migration for your `users` table.

Comment: @Namoshek here is my users migration file Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('person_id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Answer (score 0):

Add it into app\Http\Controller\Auth\VerificationController.php

```
protected function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
}
```